# Display Kannada Text in Android application

Tags: android, indic, kannada

I have a requirement to display kannada text in GCM alerts sent to an android app.

I followed these tutorials [Install Read / Write Indian Language Fonts on Android](http://www.blogsolute.com/install-indian-regional-language-fonts-android-keyboard/21947/) and
[How to Write & Read in Indian Regional Language Fonts on Android](http://androidadvices.com/write-read-indian-regional-language-fonts-android/).

Just to brief, I did following:

1. Rooted Android Device
2. Installed *ES File Explorer* (Free download from Android Market)
3. Downloaded *DroidSansFallback.ttf* Indic TrueType Font and Save it in SD Card
4. Open ES File Explorer – In settings, Enable Root Explorer and Mount
   System as RW
5. Copy the file from SD Card root and Paste it to /System/Fonts
   (Overwrite if necessary)
6. Reboot

But I ended up displaying Kannada text like this:

[image]

Whereas, I have sent ವಿಕಿಪೀಡಿಯ Thank you! from my back end server. How to display kannada exactly same as it was sent from the back end.

Comment: your need to download kannada.ttf and use the same in your app.

Comment: downloaded Kannada.ttf and saved in /system/fonts/ but still no luck. I downloaded Kannada.ttf from here http://www.4shared.com/get/9UPh-iIk/Kannada_Font.html.

Comment: no put it into your assests/fonts/kannada.ttf and set the typeface for your text

Comment: also the .ttf does not work. i just tried it out. you will probably have to find another one.

Comment: find another one as in? Do I need to download Kannada.ttf from elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Which Android version is it?

Versions before 4 don't have proper Kannada rendering support even if you supply a font, so it shows the *matras* separately from the consonants.

Where are you showing this text? It *may* work if you try to show it in the web browser, because web browsers have their own rendering engines. Try both the stock WebKit browser and Mozilla's Firefox for Android. Depending on your device and Android version, it may or may not work.

If it works in WebKit and you need it in an app, try integrating WebKit in your app instead of using regular text display.

Another thing you can try is to render your text as an image on the server and show the user that image. It won't be perfect, but it will be readable. (That's the technique that the Opera Mini Android browser uses, last time I checked.)

And hey, kudos for trying to make it work in Kannada!

Comment: Android version is 4 (ICS)

Answer (score 0):

The simpler method to read Kannada on web is by using Opera Mini application which is of course available in the Playstore.

1. Download Opera Mini
2. Type "about:config" in the URL
3. Enable  `bitmap fonts for complex scripts` I mean make it `YES`

Now you can easily read Kannada script!

You can't type or Read Kannada regular message or Whatsapp messages though. But having a primitive Android phone which is not Rooted this is the best you can get I guess!